# Java source code for branch and price

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, solver, software, java

Is there any Java source code (or framework) to implement and solve MILP using the branch and price method?

AFAIK, [jORLib](http://coin-or.github.io/jorlib/) is a framework to implement B&P using Java, but it does not have any clear documents or active mailing list.

Comment: Are you looking for a (open-source) B&P framework fully written in java, or any B&P solver with a java interface?

Comment: Many frameworks for B&P written in C/C++, but in Java, there isn't any more.

Answer (score 6):

I found a manual in Coin-OR Github page where they explained the implementation of the method through 3 different examples.
You can find the document in [this](http://coin-or.github.io/jorlib/manual/manual.pdf) web address

Comment: Thanks. I read it. It has some methods to implement. I have tried to use jORLib as a library and for the algorithmic package, it works fine, but for the B&P package, it needs to some specific libraries and features to implement that they don't have any clear documents. Do you (or someone) know how to do it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'it needs some specific libraries and features to implement'? There's nothing particular needed to implement the branch-and-price. In fact, Section 3 of the aforementioned document gives a complete working example. Moreover, implementations of these working example are also included in the repository: https://github.com/coin-or/jorlib/tree/master/jorlib-demo